# Django 1.10 - Cannot resolve keyword '__' into field. Join on '__' not permitted

Tags: python, django

I am trying to make a chart using [chartjs](http://www.chartjs.org/) for showing all statistics of a poll votes. This is for a specific year with 12 months.

For example,

Are you a programmer?

1. Yes
2. No

I would like to show in chart - how many votes users give to 12 months of a year. I ll draw 2 lines in chart that represents `Yes` and `No` answers statistics with levels `Jauary - December`.

I already made all models and they work perfectly.

But when in `poll` detail page I try to get 12 months statistics of vote record, get an error. Here is view code to get record counts -

```
vote_records = Vote.objects.filter(question = question_record, pub_date__year = current_year).values_list('pub_date__month').count()
```

Here `pub_date` is the `Vote` model publish date -

```
pub_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Error is -

> Cannot resolve keyword 'month' into field. Join on 'pub_date' not
>   permitted.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Regardless of the reason -- if you're only going to count them, why is the values_list needed?

Comment: I am pretty new to `Django`. What I am trying to get a `list` not `dictionaries`

Comment: But count() will return a single number, not a list.

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake here, what I imagined `values_list('pub_date__month').count()` would generate the list of all votes count of 12 months. Like [12, 4,..] for [`January`, 'February', ...]

Comment: How can I get that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can generate query as follows:

```py
vote_records = Vote.objects.filter(
    question=question_record, pub_date__year=current_year
).values_list(
    'pub_date', flat=True
)
```

> We are using flat key because

> It gives list tuple as given :

> > [(datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 15, 5, 3, 875344),),]

> > After using flat = True it is

> > [(datetime.datetime(2016, 11, 11, 15, 5, 3, 875344)]

We can count Month's as follows:

```
dMonthsCount = {}

for i in vote_records:
    if i.month in d:
        dMonthsCount[i.month] = dMonthsCount[i.month] + 1
    else:
        dMonthsCount[i.month] = 1

#Here key is month number and value is count
#dMonthsCount = {10: 5, 11: 8, 4: 3}

#We can also convert as follow: 
Months_dict = {1:'January', 2:'February', 3:'March', 4:'April', 5:'May', 6:'June', 7:'July',
              8:'August', 9:'September', 10:'October', 11:'November', 12:'December'}
MonthsCount={}
for i in dMonthsCount:
  MonthsCount[Months_dict[i]] = dMonthsCount[i]

#MonthsCount = {'April': 3, 'November': 8, 'October': 5}
```

Comment: Super answer! One edit needs -

`if i.month in d and i.month in dMonthsCount:
    dMonthsCount[i.month] = dMonthsCount[i.month] + 1
`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed in comments, if you only need to count something, you don't have to use `values_list`.

And the reason you get this error is because when you use double underscore in `values_list`, django treats it like a foreign key, attempts to make a join and fails. In order to get years as a list, you should write your code as follows:

```
vote_records = Vote.objects.filter(question = question_record, 
                                   pub_date__year = current_year).values_list('pub_date')
vote_records = [x.year for x in vote_records]
```